# json parsing error in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple springboot program which takes a json and prints it. The main intention was to do json validator package usage, but the current context is on the basic request parsing. The problem is when i tryy to map the input request into an class entity, it is giving the below error : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",.

- **Controller  ( Hello.java ) :**

  ```
      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = "application/json")
      public ResponseEntity<String> welcome(
              @RequestBody DemoEntity demoEntity )
      {
          System.out.println(demoEntity.getName());
          String response ="success";
          return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
      }
  }
  ```
- **Java Class entity :**

  public class DemoEntity implements Serializable {

  ```
      @JsonProperty("name")
      private String name;
      @JsonProperty("no")
      private int no;

      public int getNo() {
          return no;
      }

      public void setNo(int no) {
          this.no = no;
      }

      public String getName() {
          return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }

      DemoEntity(String name)
      {
          this.name = name;
      }
  }
  ```

  - **Complete Exception :**

  {
      "timestamp": 1497594485418,
      "status": 400,
      "error": "Bad Request",
      "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
      "message": "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@75be93a7; line: 1, column: 3]",
      "path": "/welcome"
  }

**Sample input** request in the body :
{"name":"Roopesh", "no":123123}

Comment: The "sample input" is unlikely to lead to this error message since it does not contain a single `-`  sign. Please show the exact input leading to this error.

Comment: Your example input doesn't correspond to Exception. Exception says that there is an unexpected character '-' but I don't see it in sample input.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work on my machine. You only have to add empty constructor to  DemoEntity.

Comment: Here is the request sample :  curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/welcome \
  -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'name: test' \
  -H 'postman-token: 8e87369d-e2e2-ab25-eadd-f40f0682e593' \
  -F 'demoEntity={"name":"Roopesh", "no":"123123"}'

Comment: Tried using curl, POSTman both, but same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You send incorrect request. Use `curl -X POST localhost:8090/one -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'name: test' -H 'postman-token: 8e87369d-e2e2-ab25-eadd-f40f0682e593' -d '{"name":"Roopesh", "no":"123123"}'`

1. Don't sent `demoEntity=`. Body should contains just json itself.
2. Use `-d` key to send data. `-F` is for multipart body. It is a little bit different.

Answer (score 5):

Incase if you are using Postman client to test your Rest API, there are chances wherein you must be adding body in under tab **"form-data"** rather **"raw"**.

Comment: yes, I face the same problem by sending in raw helped me, the property name must be in double quotes and if a string value is there then double quote for numeric value works without a double quote.