# Error when executing POST request which returns a list using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I created a Mock service to simulate a POST request with a body like this:

```
{
  "DOSID": "DP02213",
  "RegionsID": "31",
  "DistrictsID": "88",
  "ApprovalDate": "09/10/2020",
  "ExpiryDate": "15/10/2020",
  "ItemsList": [
    {
      "Itemlookupcode": "1SBRJUOR00CJ3050H001",
      "Quantity": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

and it has a response as below:

```
{
    "DeliveryDateList": [
        "2020-10-22T00:00:00+02:00",
        "2020-10-24T00:00:00+02:00"
    ]
}
```

The screen shot below describe the mock service:

[image: POST RESTTEMPLATE]

I created a java classes for the request and the response, then I created this java class:

```
public class GetProposedDateRestClient {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Autowired
    public List<GetProposedDateResponseHeader> getProposedDate(GetProposedDateRequestHeader requestHeader) {


        String theUrl = "https://2760f38d-a7a0-4a9b-aee6-3cd331e0c8fc.mock.pstmn.io/GetProposedDates";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<GetProposedDateResponseHeader> result = null;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<GetProposedDateRequestHeader> entity = new HttpEntity<GetProposedDateRequestHeader>(
                requestHeader, headers);
        try {
        ResponseEntity<List<GetProposedDateResponseHeader>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.POST,
                entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<GetProposedDateResponseHeader>>() {} );
        result = responseEntity.getBody();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

And finally I got this error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@29eb092b; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: Did you try to return a object that contains the list inside ResponseEntity instead of the list directly? I assume that error is because the json response starts with a square brace and it cannot be serialized

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582670/json-parsing-error-in-springboot) answer, I hope it work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response @robocode but i want to get reponse as shown in the mock service : {
    "DeliveryDateList": [
        "2020-10-22T00:00:00+02:00",
        "2020-10-24T00:00:00+02:00"
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

Your response is a JsonObject and not a JsonArray. Instead of  `List<GetProposedDateResponseHeader> result = responseEntity.getBody();`, give this a shot.
`GetProposedDateResponseHeader result = responseEntity.getBody();`

Comment: yes Sir you ara right my response is a JsonObject so this code fixes the problem :

responseEntity = restTemplate.postForObject( theUrl, requestHeader, GetProposedDateResponseHeader.class );

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about the response type, i expected a JsonArray as response type but it is a JsonObject so this code works for me :

```
responseEntity = restTemplate.postForObject( theUrl, requestHeader, GetProposedDateResponseHeader.class );
```